why does the difference quotient where h = FLT_MIN always equals 0? How can I add the smallest number possible to a float?
I am trying to find the slope of a Bezier curve using the difference quotient:
( f(x + h) - f(x) ) / h
In calculus we usually use limits where we assume h is infinitely small and we evaluate the formula to find f'(x) which is the derivative formula.
Here, I wanted to try a similar concept and make h equal to FLT_MIN or FLT_TRUE_MIN which is supposed to be the smallest positive float value, and add it to 't' to approximate adding the smallest number possible to 't'. However, when I run getApproxNormal(0.5f) I just get 0 or NaN instead of somewhere in the ballpark of what the normal vector ratio should be.
sf::vector2f is a simple class that defines a mathematical vector with two coordinates (x and y)
#include <cmath>
#include <float.h>
class Vec2f //sf::vector2f
{
public:
    float x, y;
    Vec2f() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vec2f(float X, float Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    friend Vec2f operator- (const Vec2f& a)
    {
        return Vec2f(-a.x, -a.y);
    }
    friend Vec2f operator- (const Vec2f& left, const Vec2f& right)
    {
        return Vec2f(left.x - right.x, left.y - right.y);
    }
    friend Vec2f operator/ (const Vec2f& left, float right)
    {
        return Vec2f(left.x / right, left.y / right);
    }
};

const Vec2f _p0(0, 0);
const Vec2f _p1(0, 100);
const Vec2f _p2(100, 100);

Vec2f getBezierPoint(float t) // float t is a value between 0 and 1 that
//determines the percentage of the curve to sample the point for
//example when t = 0.5 that's 50% between the start and the endpoint of
//the bezier curve
{
    float x = powf(1 - t, 2) * _p0.x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * _p1.x + std::pow(t, 2) * _p2.x;
    float y = powf(1 - t, 2) * _p0.y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * _p1.y + std::pow(t, 2) * _p2.y;
    return Vec2f(x, y);
}
float getApproxNormal(float t)
{
    Vec2f d = (getBezierPoint(t + FLT_MIN) // issue is that both calls 
        //return the same value even after adding FLT_MIN
        - getBezierPoint(t)) / FLT_MIN;

    return -(d.x / d.y); // returns the negative inverse of the derivative
}

void main()
{
    float normal = getApproxNormal(0.5f); // return NaN
}


As far as I know, it's difficult for a float to represent a larger number without sacrificing the smaller digits causing data loss in the least significant digits. This must mean that the smallest number I can add to a larger number varies depending on the larger number. If this is the case, how can I find the smallest number that I can add to a given float value.

What is in t? How to run your code? Can you post a [mre]?

It may or may not be 0.0f but it is really a very very small positive number (and dividing by it is going to explode your answer).  Anyway you should not use this approximation for the derivate, the derivate of a bezier function is a function too and you should calculate that to avoid numerical instabilities.

@PepijnKramer Answers in the answers section please.

"Float inaccuracies" aren't a real thing. You have to analyze floating-point arithmetic according to the rules of floating-point arithmetic; they're different from the rules for real numbers. If you think of floating-point math as broken real math you'll never make sense of it. When you do int x = 1; std::cout << x/4; you're not surprised to get 0, even though we all know it's .25. Approach floating-point math the same way.

If we imagine floating point numbers are implemented as decimals with a 5 digit number and a 2 digit exponent then the smallest possible number would be 1.0000 * 10 -99 if we add this to 1.0000 * 10 0 then after rounding to our 5 digit number we still have 1.0000 * 10 0. Floating point numbers are essentially implemented in the same way just with binary mantissa and exponent rather than decimal ones.
Therefore adding FLT_MIN to anything other than another very small number will likely round out to the same number. What you actually want to do is find the next nearest number, fortunately c++ provides functions to do this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter:
getApproxNormal(float t)
{
    float next = std::nextafter(t, FLT_MAX);
    float diff = next - t;
    Vec2f d = (getBezierPoint(next)
             - getBezierPoint(t)) / diff; 

    return -(d.x / d.y); // returns the negative inverse of the derivative
}

Note that due to the limitations of floating point accuracy you might not get the exact answer you expect.

The next representable number generally will not work well with a numerical derivative calculation. Consider that if the derivative of f(x) is, say, 1/3, then f(x+u), where u is the ULP of x, differs from f(x) by only 1/3 of its ULP, so f(x+u) may equal f(x), and the numerical derivative would be calculated as zero. Something around the “middle” of the precision may work better, something like |x|•sqrt(FLT_EPSILON).

@EricPostpischil I was answering the questions Any idea what's causing this? why is FLT_MIN still 0?, the question isn't how do I accurately calculate a numerical derivative

This answer states “What you actually want to do is find the next nearest number.” That is not what OP wants to do.

@EricPostpischil it might not be what they need to do to get the best results but it is the question that they've asked

Nowhere in the question does OP make any mention of wanting to find the next nearest number.

@EricPostpischil not explicitly no but they're trying to add the smallest possible float onto a number, that indicates that they were trying to find the next number

@AlanBirtles Finding the next nearest number Is indeed my objective by adding the smallest possible float value to a number. I tried using std::nextafter and it's working as intended. I'm also able to find that small difference 'h' between the nextafter(t, FLT_MAX) result and t. and the normal vector results are actually still accurate enough to give me whole numbers where I expect them to be after comparing the results with a Desmos example. Thank you so much for your solution and your humble contribution to the community .

@stuck_zipper: Unfortunately, you have taken bad advice. By using, for h, the increment to the next value, you also have f(x+h) very close to f(x) (except in cases where the derivative is very large). This means that f(x+h)−f(x) will have very low precision, and so your calculation of the derivative will have a lot of error. For example, using decimal to illustrate, consider f(x) = 1/3•x. If we have x=1 and h=.000001, then  f(1) = .333333 and f(1.00001) = .333334 (due to rounding), and we calculate (f(x+h)−f(x))/h = .000001/.000001 = 1…

… What you actually should do is choose an h in the “middle” with respect to precision. Say, for the above example, h = .001. Then f(x) = f(1) = .333333, f(x+h) = f(1.001) = .333667, and (f(x+h)−f(x))/h = .000334/.001 = .334. That is a much closer result to the actual derivative. You want an h small enough that f(x+h) changes by something close to the derivative (not affected much by second-order effects) but large enough that the difference between f(x) and f(x+h) is large compared to the resolution of the floating-point format.

@EricPostpischil The advice I was given is what works for me in helping me understand the bigger picture if what's happening. Especially understanding that If I want to add the smallest possible number to a float, I should use std::nextafter. understanding this can also be useful for other applications in the future. If I really was concerned about exact accuracy, I would just use the Bezier derivative formula.

The result of adding t + FLT_MIN can be t. This is how floating point numbers work. FLT_MIN is the minimum normalized positive value, but this doesn't mean that if you add it to, say, 0.5, then you will get a number other than 0.5. Floating point numbers allow you to work with very small values and with very large values, but not small and large at the same time. The increment step depends on the exponent of the value.



sign
exponent (8 bits)
mantissa (23 bits)




31
30 - 23
22 - 0



Here is a simple example (that doesn't take into account the overflow of the mantissa):
float t = 0.5f;
auto i = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&t);
i++;    // mantissa increment
float next_t = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&i);
std::cout.precision(10);
std::cout << next_t << " - " << t << " = " << next_t - t;

Output:
0.5000000596 - 0.5 = 5.960464478e-08

That is, the nearest number greater than 0.5 differs from it by 5.960464478e-08.

”FLT_MIN is the minimum value that can be obtained as a result of calculations” is not correct. The minimum value that can be the result of a float arithmetic operation is −∞. The minimum positive value that can be the result of a float arithmetic operation is FLT_TRUE_MIN. FLT_MIN is the minimum normal float value.

Reinterpreting addresses as different pointer types is not a proper way to access the bytes representing a value. And, in this case, it is not necessary, as C and C++ provide nextafter and nexttoward functions for getting successive floating-point values.
